# How does the contancy of a function over a distance $a$ translates into its Fourier components?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, fourier-transform

In the book of Kardar, Statistical Physics of Fields, on page 20, it is given that

> It is important to emphasize that while $\mathbf{x}$ is treated as a continuous variable, the function $\vec{m}(\mathbf{x})$ does not exhibit any variations at distances of the order of the lattice spacing, i.e. its Fourier transform involves only wavevectors less than some upper cutoff $\Lambda \sim 1 / a$.

However, I don't understand how the author argues that the Fouries series of $m$ doesn't contain wavevectors of magnitude higher than $1/a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll treat the 1d case to ease notation. Your original function $f$ can be thought of as being defined on a lattice of spacing $a$ (that is, it is defined on $a\mathbb{Z}$). This implies that its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ has period at most $2\pi/a$. Indeed, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\hat{f}(k+\frac{2\pi}{a}n) = \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{i(k+\frac{2\pi}{a}n)ax} f(ax) = \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{ikax} \underbrace{e^{i2\pi nx}}_{=1} f(ax) = \hat{f}(k).
$$

Comment: But then isn't $2\pi/a$ a low bound for the period, and hence for the wavevector?

Comment: It’s an upper bound on the period.